# "Network cable unplugged" on Cloned Hyper-V VM

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, hyper-v, nat

I created a VM on one Hyper-V host (actually Windows Server 2022 Core).  The VM is running Windows Server 2022.  Works great.  I have NAT running on the host and the VM is on 192.168.1.2 and using 192.168.1.1 on the host as its gateway.  I need to clone that setup on multiple servers, so I took that VM's virtual drive and did sysprep to it.

On host 2, I set up NAT, created a VM, replaced its vhdx with the sysprep'ed vhdx, and started it up.  It's working fine, except for networking.  In Device Manager was a hidden "Microsoft Hyper-V Network Adapter #1", and an enabled #2.  I uninstalled #1, then changed the IPv4 properties of #2 for static IP.  However, it's showing "Network cable unplugged", even after shutting down the VM and starting it again.  How do I plug in its virtual network cable?

For details, here's what I had done on both hosts for NAT:
New-VMSwitch -SwitchName NAT -SwitchType Internal
New-NetIPAddress -IPAddress 192.168.1.1 -PrefixLength 24 -InterfaceAlias "vEthernet (NAT)"
New-NetNAT -Name NATNetwork -InternalIPInterfaceAddressPrefix 192.168.1.0/24

The command I used to sysprep was: sysprep.exe /oobe /generalize /shutdown /mode:vm

I tried resetting tcp, ipv4 and ipv6 (e.g. netsh int tcp reset), and restarted the VM, with no change.

Any ideas?  Was there some step I needed to take with the network adapter before running sysprep?

Thanks in advance

Comment: On the VM settings reattach the network adapter to the proper switch. When the VM moves from one host to another it is not recognizing the switch on the new host as matching the one from the old host so it’s probably disconnected.

Comment: Thanks, @Appleoddity.  I thought that since 2 hosts had a virtual switch with the same name, and that the VM was attached to that virtual switch, that when I copied the vhdx to the 2nd host, it would be hooked up.  Perhaps behind the scenes it's linking by GUID or something.  Anyway, I just needed to: Get-VM "<VM name>" | Get-VMNetworkAdapter | Connect-VMNetworkAdapter -SwitchName "<switch name>".